# run powershell script without add publishsettings file

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, automation, powershell-3.0

I am using powershell script, using this i create/setup vm in azure. I want to run powershell script without azure credentials (right now i am using as below but I don't want to my.publishsettings or publishsettings details in powershell script).

*create_vm.ps1*

`...
azure account import D:\my.publishsettings
...`

Is there any want to do same. please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways by which you can connect to and manage your Azure Subscription - One is using `X509 Certificate` (which is what you're doing when you use `publishsettings` file) and the other is using `Azure AD`.

Please see this link for detailed instructions on how you can use `Azure AD` to manage your Azure Subscriptions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/. Scroll down to section titled `How to: Connect to your subscription`.